# php - I/O streaming

Tags: php, io, stream, pipe

I was looking at the documentation here for I/O streaming in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php

I have a question about how this works - if I were piping say 10,000 lines of input per second from a linux command into a php script, and the script were only able to process 1,000 within a second, what would happen? Would the PHP script just fall way behind or would it just skip data and get the latest 1000? I realize this may be considered a stupid question, but I thought I'd ask anyway.

Comment: Generally, the call to `fwrite` in the generator will hang until there is a matching `fread` in the script reading.

Comment: @Mitch Thanks for your response - so if I wanted the most recent 1000, I could start a thread to simply keep reading, and keep track of the last 1000 things read?

Comment: That would be one way, yes.  You could also pipe through `tail -n 1000` if you don't need the _running_ last 1000.